# (Bash) $user@aol.com email availability checker

Tags: bash, aol

So, I'm trying to set up a script in bash to send a request to aim.com's signup form, where it allows you to check if an ID is able to be made like so:

https://new.aol.com/productsweb/?promocode=827692&ncid=txtlnkuswebr00000073
- Choose a username

if $user = available then $continue; else show "Sorry, that username isn't available.".

Once that concept is down, I'll have it running through a list of a good 100 or so to see if any of these are able to be re-made.

If anyone can just point me in a starting direction, that would be awesome! 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the referenced page, when you click the `Check` button, it sends a `POST` request to the following URL:

https://new.aol.com/productsweb/subflows/ScreenNameFlow/AjaxSNAction.do

With the following (required) parameter: `s`. This parameter needs to be set to the username you're testing for.

If the username exists, a "*reloadEverything*" message appears. If the username doesn't exist, a "*toggleSNField*" message appears.

If you want a real "*Sorry, that username isn't available.*" message instead of the "reloadEverything", add two more parameters: `l` and `f` - and they both need to *also* be the username you're testing.

To accomplish this, you could iterate through your list of usernames and make a `POST` request with each and then just parse the response matching the above strings (the *reloadEverything* string is longer than that - so you could just do a substring match).

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you! That's definitely a great help.