# (Bash) Submitting post data to an online form to check username availability

Tags: bash, post, curl, aol

Firstly asked at: [(Bash) $user@aol.com email availability checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888407/bash-useraol-com-email-availability-checker) 
(with a well thought out beginning. Thanks again!)

I'm looking to expand on this a bit:

I'm trying to use either Curl, or a simple POST command (neither have proven working yet) to try to validate a list of usernames that I have to the following page:

https://new.aol.com/productsweb/

Essentially, this will be an availability checker for @aol.com email addresses.

It doesn't have to neat, clean, or pretty, as long as it works.

Does anyone have any idea where I can go from here?

Comment: Do people still use AOL?

Answer (score 1):

The following `bash` script using `cURL` command can check the availability of an email :

```
testemail=foobar # @aol.com
out=$(
    curl \
        -A "Mozilla/5.0" \
        -L \
        -b /tmp/c \
        -c /tmp/c \
        -s \
        -e 'https://new.aol.com/productsweb/' \
        -d "d=aol.com&f=test&l=test2&m=&s=$testemail" \
        'https://new.aol.com/productsweb/subflows/ScreenNameFlow/AjaxSNAction.do'
)

if [[ $out == *toggleSNField* ]]; then
    echo "email $testemail@aol.com is available"
elif [[ $out == *Error* ]]; then
    echo >&2 "an error occured while processing $testemail@aol.com"
else
    echo >&2 "$testemail@aol.com is unavailable"
fi
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- to understand what's going on, I use `firefox` & `firebug` addon, see `XHR` tab in this [screenshot](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1350423795.png) ²
- I search in the POST what `firefox` sends to the AOL server
- then, I use `cURL` to do the same

See `man curl` for further details.

² this is an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request

Comment: You have by far been the most help of all, Sputnick. I really appreciate it! Do you think there might be a way to make it read a .txt file and process them in a loop? I'm new to using curl.

Comment: Yes, see http://sputnick-area.net/pasteme/352 and adapt the last lines to your own file.

Comment: Your structure is awesome, though I'm not sure that it's working. I threw in a random test email (haxedulollmaoomg) to see if it was generating active results. It stated that it was unavailable, but upon signup, it was. Think there might be something missing here? I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: The script was modified to display an error & the site seems changed or it's a temporary failure.